# Unable to see the saved non recurrences event in calendar view in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: jsom, sharepoint-calendar, recurring-events

```
$scope.submitEvent = function () {
                $scope.calculateEndDate()
                var tags = "";
                var termsArray = new Array();
                var targetAudiencefield = "";
                var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
                var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Event');
                var oListItem
                if (window.location.href.indexOf("NewForm") > 0) {
                    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
                    oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
                }
                else if (window.location.href.indexOf("EditForm") > 0) {
                    oListItem = oList.getItemById(editEventtId);
                }
                oListItem.set_item('Title', $scope.eventData.title);
                oListItem.set_item('Location', $scope.eventData.location);
                oListItem.set_item('Relevant_x0020_URL', $scope.eventData.link);
                oListItem.set_item('fAllDayEvent', $scope.eventData.cb5);
                oListItem.set_item('Notes', $scope.eventData.Body);
                oListItem.set_item('EventType', 1);


                var eventDate,
                    endDate,
                    selectedItem = $scope.eventData.selectedItem;

                if (selectedItem === 'Never') {
                    //oListItem.set_item('fRecurrence', false);

                    eventDate = getDateWithTime($scope.eventData.startDate, $scope.eventData.startTime);
                    endDate = getDateWithTime($scope.eventData.endDate, $scope.eventData.endTime);
                } else {
                    oListItem.set_item('fRecurrence', true);
                    var recurrenceData = getRecurrenceData(selectedItem);
                    oListItem.set_item('RecurrenceData', recurrenceData);

                    var repatEndate;
                    if (selectedItem === 'Daily') {
                        eventDate = getDateWithTime($scope.daily.startDate, $scope.eventData.startTime);
                        repatEndate = $scope.eventData.data=="End by" ?$scope.daily.windowEnd : $scope.repeatEnd
                        endDate = getDateWithTime(repatEndate, $scope.eventData.endTime);
                    } else if (selectedItem === 'Weekly') {
                        eventDate = getDateWithTime($scope.weekly.startDate, $scope.eventData.startTime);
                        repatEndate = $scope.eventData.data == "End by" ? $scope.weekly.windowEnd : $scope.repeatEnd
                        endDate = getDateWithTime(repatEndate, $scope.eventData.endTime);
                    } else if (selectedItem === 'Monthly') {
                        eventDate = getDateWithTime($scope.monthly.startDate, $scope.eventData.startTime);
                        repatEndate = $scope.eventData.data == "End by" ? $scope.monthly.windowEnd : $scope.repeatEnd
                        endDate = getDateWithTime(repatEndate, $scope.eventData.endTime);
                    } else {
                        eventDate = getDateWithTime($scope.yearly.startDate, $scope.eventData.startTime);
                        repatEndate = $scope.eventData.data == "End by" ? $scope.yearly.windowEnd : $scope.repeatEnd
                        endDate = getDateWithTime(repatEndate, $scope.eventData.endTime);
                    }
                }

                if ($scope.eventData.cb5) {
                    oListItem.set_item('EventDate', getDateWithFixedTime(eventDate, 0, 0, 0, 0));
                    oListItem.set_item('EndDate', getDateWithFixedTime(endDate, 23, 59, 0, 0));
                } else {
                    oListItem.set_item('EventDate', eventDate);
                    if (endDate != "Invalid Date")
                        oListItem.set_item('EndDate', endDate);
                    else
                        oListItem.set_item('EndDate', eventDate);

                    // oListItem.set_item('EndDate', new Date(new Date($scope.eventData.endDate).setTime(new Date($scope.eventData.endTime).getTime())));
                }
                if (selectedItem != 'Never') {
                    var newGuid = guid()
                    oListItem.set_item('UID', newGuid);
                }
                //  oListItem.set_item('EndDate', new Date($scope.eventData.endDate + new Date($scope.eventData.endTime).toTimeString()).toUTCString());
                oListItem.set_item('Cover_x0020_Image', $scope.CurrentPost.RollupImage.URL);
                // oListItem.set_item('Notes', $scope.CurrentPost.Body);
                // oListItem.set_item('LatestNewsDefaultImage', _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/Site Asset/LatestNewsDefaultImg.png");
                //  oListItem.set_item('FeaturedNewsDefaultImage', _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/Site Asset/FeaturedNewsDefaultImg.png");
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.audiences.length; i++) {
                    if ($scope.audiences[i].selected === true) {
                        targetAudiencefield += $scope.audiences[i].AudienceID + ',';
                    }
                }
                targetAudiencefield += ";;;;";
                angular.forEach($scope.Tags, function (value, key) {
                    if ($scope.Tags[key].ticked === true) {
                        termsArray.push("-1;#" + $scope.Tags[key].name + "|" + $scope.Tags[key].id);
                    }
                });
                tags = termsArray.join(";#");
                var field = oList.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("Tags");
                var taxField = clientContext.castTo(field, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);
                var terms = new SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(clientContext, tags, taxField);
                taxField.setFieldValueByValueCollection(oListItem, terms);
                oListItem.set_item('Target_x0020_Audiences', targetAudiencefield);
               // oListItem.set_item('fRecurrence', false);
                oListItem.update();
                clientContext.load(oListItem);
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);

                function onQuerySucceeded() {
                    //SP.UI.ModalDialog.close(options);


                    SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose()
                    window.location = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/Event/calendar.aspx"
                    console.log('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
                }

                function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
                    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                }
```

Comment: Can you post the JSOM code here ?

Comment: I updated the question @GautamSheth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I found the solution for the issue, It happens because of Event type

Single event and All-day event: Event type should be 0

Recurrence: Event type should be 1

```
if(Selected item != Never)
{
oListItem.set_item('EventType', 1);
}
else
{
oListItem.set_item('EventType', 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it as below:

```
var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);


oListItem.set_item('Title', $scope.eventData.title);
oListItem.set_item('Location', $scope.eventData.location);
oListItem.set_item('Relevant_x0020_URL', $scope.eventData.link);
oListItem.set_item('fAllDayEvent', $scope.eventData.cb5);
oListItem.set_item('Notes', $scope.eventData.Body);
oListItem.set_item('EventType', 1);


var eventDate,
    endDate,
    selectedItem = $scope.eventData.selectedItem;

if (selectedItem === 'Never') {        

    eventDate = getDateWithTime($scope.eventData.startDate, $scope.eventData.startTime);
    endDate = getDateWithTime($scope.eventData.endDate, $scope.eventData.endTime);

    oListItem.set_item('EventDate', eventDate);
    oListItem.set_item('EndDate', endDate);
} 
else {
    oListItem.set_item('fRecurrence', true);
    var recurrenceData = getRecurrenceData(selectedItem);
    oListItem.set_item('RecurrenceData', recurrenceData);

    if (selectedItem === 'Daily') {
        eventDate = getDateWithTime($scope.daily.startDate, $scope.eventData.startTime);
        endDate = getDateWithTime($scope.daily.windowEnd, $scope.eventData.endTime);
    } else if (selectedItem === 'Weekly') {
        eventDate = getDateWithTime($scope.weekly.startDate, $scope.eventData.startTime);
        endDate = getDateWithTime($scope.weekly.windowEnd, $scope.eventData.endTime);
    } else if (selectedItem === 'Monthly') {
        eventDate = getDateWithTime($scope.monthly.startDate, $scope.eventData.startTime);
        endDate = getDateWithTime($scope.monthly.windowEnd, $scope.eventData.endTime);
    } else {
        eventDate = getDateWithTime($scope.yearly.startDate, $scope.eventData.startTime);
        endDate = getDateWithTime($scope.yearly.windowEnd, $scope.eventData.endTime);
    }

    oListItem.set_item('EventDate', eventDate);
    oListItem.set_item('EndDate', endDate);
}
```

In the code that you have posted, below code is inside the `else` block. That's why I think its not setting value there is no recurrence.

```
oListItem.set_item('EventDate', eventDate);
oListItem.set_item('EndDate', endDate);
```

Comment: ya but above lines for saving the recurrence events, first IF condition is for saving the non-recurrence events, So I think setting false is a problem? Because in default there has one checkbox for recurrences,  but I kept its dropdown. @GautamSheth

Comment: Yep have edited the code, by default the Recurrence is set to false so I think you dont need to set its value. Is the event now appearing in calendar view ?

Comment: I tried to like that, Still no luck bro, It's not appearing in calendar view? @GautamSheth

Comment: Can you add full code right upto executequery ?

Comment: ya sure, can we discuss in chat?@GautamSheth

Comment: I updated the Question@GautamSheth